# Microstates and Combinations

Tags: statistical-mechanics

There are two boxes (which I will call 1 and 2) that are initially thermally isolated and have a sliding door in between them. We can write the probability of configuration $A$ in box 1 as,

$$P_1(A)=\frac{1}{\Omega_1}$$

Similarly, configuration B in box 2 is,

$$P_2(B)=\frac{1}{\Omega_2}$$

The probability of these configurations occurring simultaneously when the barrier is removed between the two boxes is,

$$P_1(A)P_2(B)=P_0(A +B)$$

Similarly,

$$\Omega_1(A)\Omega_2(B)=\Omega_0(A+B) \tag{1}$$

This is a pretty basic result that's used in $NVE$ ensembles to derive a series of interesting results.

*FYI: From here I am sketching out an idea so forgive me for not having a reference for anything below this line.*

If we define the configurations or microstates, $\Omega$, as the number of combinations of indistinguishable particles, $n$, in $r$ discrete spatial locations (ignoring momentum space for the time being), we would get:

$$\Omega_1=\frac{n_1!}{r_1!(n_1-r_1)!} \tag{2}$$

Similarly,
$$\Omega_2=\frac{n_2!}{r_2!(n_2-r_2)!} \tag{3}$$

To simplify the math for each box I will let the number of particles be $n$ and the number of spatial locations be $r$, then,

$$\Omega_1 = \Omega_2 = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} \tag{4}$$

Then by $(1)$,

$$\Omega_0 = \Omega_1 \Omega_2 = \left(\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\right)^2 \tag{5}$$

But as I have defined it, when the wall is removed between the two boxes we will get $n_0=2n$ and $r_0=2r$. Therefore,

$$\Omega_0 = \frac{(2n)!}{(2r)!(2n-2r)!} \tag{6}$$

Is there any way to show that $(5)$ and $(6)$ are equal? Maybe with Stirling's approximation?

Edit: According to Desmos, they are not equal expressions at low values. Is there something wrong with how I am thinking about this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it does actually work out using Stirling's approximation (it's a lot of annoying algebra):

$$\ln a!\approx a\ln a - a$$

First expression:

$$\ln \left( \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} \right)^2 = 2(\ln n! - \ln r! - \ln(n-r)!)$$
$$\approx 2(n\ln n - n - r\ln r + r - (n-r)\ln(n-r) + (n-r)) = 2(n\ln n-r \ln r -n\ln (n-r) + r\ln(n-r))$$

Second expression:

$$\ln \left( \frac{2n!}{2r!(2n-2r)!} \right)=\ln(2n!)-\ln(2r!)-\ln(2n-2r)!$$

$$ \approx 2n\ln2n - 2n -2r\ln2r + 2r -(2n-2r)\ln2(n-r) + (2n-2r)$$

$$ = 2[n\ln2+n\ln n-r\ln2-r\ln r-n\ln2(n-r)+r\ln2(n-r)]$$

$$=2[n\ln2+n\ln n-r\ln2-r\ln r-n\ln2-n\ln(n-r)+r\ln2+r\ln(n-r)]$$

Which after cancelling terms shows they are equal.

Edit: missed the last part of stirling's approx but it doesn't change the result

Comment: Stirling's formula: $\ln a!\approx a\ln a-a$, this last $a$ can not be ignored.

Comment: Fixed. Review and change your rating unless you see another issue